# Subquery in access: how to get previous row calculated value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've table which is a query result, with added calculation fields in X to get the net value.
Simplifying it, it would look like this:

```
period_start | period_end | gross | X | net |
|:----------:|:----------:|:-----:|:-:| ---:|
| 31.12.2007 | 31.12.2008 | 3000  |30 |2970 |
| 31.12.2008 | 30.11.2020 | 3000  |50 |2950 |
| 30.11.2020 | 30.07.2054 | 3000  |150|2850 |
```

How could I modify it to connect period_start with period_end, to show gross as previous month's net, using ms-access query?
I've tried subqueries before to get previous period value, but never in the middle of the calculation. Best result would be:

```
period_start | period_end | gross | X | net |
|:----------:|:----------:|:-----:|:-:| ---:|
| 31.12.2007 | 31.12.2008 | 3000  |30 |2970 |
| 31.12.2008 | 30.11.2020 | 2970  |50 |2920 |
| 30.11.2020 | 30.07.2054 | 2920  |150|2770 |
```

Comment: It would be something like `select *,(select gross from table1 as t1 where t1.period_end=t.period_start) as PREV_VAL from table 1 as t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the query result in another query. Consider:

```
SELECT Data.*, 
gross - Nz((SELECT Sum(x) AS SX FROM Data AS Dupe WHERE Dupe.Period_end<Data.Period_end ),0) AS AdjGross, 
gross - (SELECT Sum(x) AS SX FROM Data AS Dupe WHERE Dupe.Period_end<=Data.Period_end) AS AdjNet
FROM Data;
```

Possible alternative is to build a report based on your query and use textbox RunningSum property.

Comment: Thanks @June7, your answer gave me a bit different results (backwards), so I've switched < with > in AdjGross:

gross - Nz((SELECT Sum(x) AS SX FROM Data AS Dupe WHERE Dupe.Period_end>Data.Period_end ),0) AS AdjGross, 
AdjGross - x as AdjNet

, now it works exactly how I wanted. I wonder now, what If X was a calculated value instead of static one, based on AdjGross? A bit like circular reference, first X value based on gross, but next one based on AdjGross. Would it be still possible to solve in access?

Comment: Well, I can't make sense of that. From your original narrative, I thought X was a calculated field.